# Accessing the promise object from within the then function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, scope, promise, q

I am using the Q library of node.js . I am trying to print a report which would print the query name and the result . This is what I have . The code prints "In function undefined . How do I access the value of the promise object from within the "then" function ?

```
var queries = ["2091 OR 2092 OR 2093", 
            "2061 OR 2062",
            "2139 OR 2140 OR 2141"
            ];

var promises = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<queries.length; i++) {
    promises[i]=performSearch(queries[i]);
    promises[i].query = queries[i];
    console.log("Outside function ", promises[i].query);

    promises[i].then(function(data) {
            console.log("In function ", this.query);
            processSearchResults(data,this.query);
    });
}
Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(results) {
    endFunction();
});
```

Comment: if `performSearch` returns a promise, then `data` is also a promise.

Comment: @BenFortune: `data` is not a promise - it *must not* be a promise according to the spec?

Comment: @BenFortune data is not a promise. I have set the query property on the promise object . I want to access this property from within the then function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what I have:
>
> ```
> promises[i].then(function(data) {
>         console.log("In function ", this.query);
>         processSearchResults(data,this.query);
> });
> ```
>
> The code prints "In function undefined".

[The spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) mandates that the callback is called with nothing for the `this` value, so `this` will refer to the global (`window`) object in sloppy mode, which does not have a `.query` property. In strict mode you'd have gotten an exception when `this` was `undefined`.

> How do I access the value of the promise object from within the "then"
>   function ?

There is no special method. You usually will not need to access a promise as an object, it's only a transparent value representing the single result of an asynchronous computation. All you need to do with it is to call its `.then()` method - and inside the callback, there's no reason to access the promise object, because the information it holds is already accessible to you (`data`, and the fact that the fulfillment callback was invoked).

So if you want to access your `.query` property, you'd have to use `promises[i]` as usual. However, [you will need a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) for `i` so you'd better use `map` anyway and hold the `query` string in the closure directly instead of making it a property on a promise object:

```
var queries = ["2091 OR 2092 OR 2093", 
            "2061 OR 2062",
            "2139 OR 2140 OR 2141"
            ];

var promises = queries.map(function(query) {
    var promise = performSearch(query);
    console.log("Outside function ", query);
    var processedPromise = promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log("In function ", query);
        return processSearchResults(data, query);
    });
    return processedPromise; // I assume you don't want the unprocessed results
});
Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(processedResults) {
    endFunction(processedResults);
});
```

Comment: Thanks . Works as expected .